# Comparison operators Bash

Tags: bash, comparison, comparison-operators

Is it possible to collect "True or False" from a comparison in bash? Without using "if".

Example ( let me make in another language )

```
x = 1
y = 1
z = x == y 
print(z) #Returns true
```

How is it in bash if is possible?

**Solved**

```
x=1
y=1
[[ $x -eq $y ]] && z=true || z=false
echo $z #Returns true
```

**Thanks @[Viktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9098014/viktor-khilin) & @[randomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404556/randomir)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `test`, without `if`:

```
x=1
y=1
[ $"{x}" -eq $"{y}" ] && echo "True" || echo "False"
```

Here, if `x` equal `y`, logical AND (`&&`) works, and script echo "True".

If `x` not equal`, logical OR (`||`) works, script echo "False".

Upd. by @[randomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404556/randomir) advice, another available solutions:

```
(( $"x" == $"y" )) && echo True || echo False
```

Or:

```
[[ $"a" == $"y" ]] && echo True || echo False
```

Comment: Why do you use `$"{x}"` instead of `"$x"` ?

Comment: @M.Becerra It's a habit. We need not `{}` in this case, but it useful when you do smth like that in your code: `echo "Just example ${filename}.tar.gz`, so bash knows that my variable named `filename`, not `filename.tar.gz`

Comment: Since OP is interested in a `bash` solution, maybe it would be worthwhile to also mention the arithmetic-only test, `(( x == y )) && echo True || echo False`. And the `[[ $x -eq $y ]]`, where no quoting is necessary.

Comment: Achieved Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you have stored `true` or `false` in a variable, you can use that in conditionals directly:

```
#!/bin/sh
X=1
Y=1
if test "$X" -eq "$Y"; then Z=true; else Z=false; fi

echo "Z is $Z"

# you can just use Z here
if "$Z"; then do_ something; fi
```

There is no expression which directly yields a boolean value, but you could probably wrap the if/else in a function if you really wanted to (untested):

```
#!/bin/sh
bool_eq() {
  if test "$1" -eq "$2"; then echo true; else echo false; fi
}

X=1
Y=1
Z="$(bool_eq "$X" "$Y")"

echo "Z is $Z"

# you can just use Z here
if "$Z"; then do_ something; fi
```